# Update not working after installing up SSL

Tags: ssl

I install on your site SSL certificate and after that I can't update wordpress.
It give me this error :  ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.

Best Regards

Comment: Did you update your admin settings to include https?  Admin > Settings > General > WordPress Address (URL) & Site Address (URL)?  This is just a guess really.

Comment: Yeah, more information is needed for us to help you further... But @RiddleMeThis guess is spot on.
This error generally happens with Cross Domain requests (which get blocked in most cases). It's also good to know what steps you took to use https.